# Is there a "better" or a "better performance" way of looping though a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I am looping through a list of strings to see if that string is contained in the values of a dictionary and then trying to remove that string from the value.

Currently I do it like this:

```
Dictionary<String, String> formValues = new Dictionary<String, String>();
formValues["key1"] = "the something at";
formValues["key2"] = "the something on";
formValues["key3"] = "the something is";

string prepositionList = "at,as,if,of,the,to,a,an,it,is,by,its";
List<string> prepositionListValues = new List<string>(prepositionList.Split(','));

foreach (string preposition in prepositionListValues)
{
    List<string> keys = new List<string>(formValues.Keys);
    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        if (formValues[key] != null)
        {
            if (formValues[key].Contains(preposition))
            {
                formValues[key] = formValues[key].Replace(preposition, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To me, this seems a bit long winded. Is there a "better" way of doing this?

Comment: Why has my question been downvoted?

Comment: If the dictionary is large then this is quite inefficient; remember, dictionaries are designed to make fast lookup of the value associated with a given key, not fast lookup of a given value!  If this is an operation that you have to do a lot then you should have *two* dictionaries; a regular "forward" dictionary and then a "reverse" dictionary that maps from values back to a sequence of associated keys. Keeping two dictionaries in sync like this uses more space and time on each operation, but your operation gets much cheaper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate the KeyvaluePair entries of the underlying IEnumerable:

```
foreach (var kvp in formValues)
{
    if (kvp.Value != null && kvp.Value.Contains(preposition))
    {
        formValue[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value.Replace(preposition, "");
    }
}
```

Warning: modifying a collection while enumerating it is rarely a good plan. In this case, I supose it's ok.

### Anyways,

what you are really trying to achieve here is a multiple-replace.

Why not use a regular expression:

```
private static readonly myRegex = new Regex("at|as|if|of|the|to|a|an|it|is|by|its", 
                RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// ..

someValue = myRegex.Replace(someValue, "");
```

I showed `IgnoreCase` just in case you didn't know about that. It looks like it could be applicable to your code.

Comment: Since you've got the KVP, just do `kvp.Value` instead of retrieving from the Dictionary with each run

Comment: You can't assign to `kvp.Value` though

Comment: @Blorgbeard I thought you could. You shouldn't be able to assign to kvp.Key, obviously. Need to check

Comment: @sehe nope, KeyValuePair is an immutable struct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx

Comment: You'd have to cheat a little bit, like: `foreach (var kvp in formValues.ToArray())` so you don't modify the iterated collection as you're iterating through it.

Comment: @JoeEnos That's more than cheating a bit. That's probably defeating the whole "optimization". However, see edited post for more potential for optimization

Comment: @sehe I like the idea of using regular expressions. It looks a lot tidier and better than what I was doing. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @sehe I have still have to create a list of the keys from the dictionary and loop through those doing `formValues[key]` as I cannot change the value of a dictionary item while looping through it. But the regular expression works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> Clean( Dictionary<string,string> dictionary , params string[] words )
{
  string pattern = @"\b(" + string.Join( "|" , words.Select( Regex.Escape ) ) + @")\b" ;
  Regex rx = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ;

  foreach ( string key in dictionary.Keys )
  {
    dictionary[key] = rx.Replace(dictionary[key],"") ;
  }

  return dictionary ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance you might consider some kind of binary search tree, e.g. Ternary search tree.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a automata in that each change in state is a specific character.
Then if you want to find something you just have to follow the automata tree and get to the terminal point in which the searched thing lies.